$p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is monic and irreducible, $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are the complex roots, if $\prod f(a_i) = 1$, then $f \in Z[x]/I(p)$ is a unit
The problem raised up from the discussion of the units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I(p)$.
Suppose $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is monic and irreducible, $\deg(p) = n$, and $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ are all complex roots
I defined a norm $N$ on $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I(p)$ such that $N: f \mapsto |\prod_{i=1}^n f(a_i)|$
Since $\prod_{i=1}^n f(a_i)$ is a symmetric function with integer coefficient, we can rewrite $\prod_{i=1}^n f(a_i) = g(e_1, \cdots, e_n)$. $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric functions of $a_1, \cdots, a_n$ and $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. By Vieta theorem, $e_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\prod_{i=1}^n f(a_i) = g(e_1, \cdots, e_n) \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Thus, we have if $(I(p)+f) \mid (I(p)+1)$, then $N(f) \mid N(1) = 1$ and $N(f) = 1$.
Then I want to check whether the only if statement works.
I know that if $\deg(p) = 2$, the answer is yes. Because $a_2 = -c_1-a_1$ where $c_1$ is the coefficient of linear term of $p$ by Vieta theorem. Thus, $f(a_1)f(a_2) = f(a_1)f(-c_1-a_1) = 1$. Therefore, $f(-c_1-x) = g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I(p)$
Is this true when $\deg(p)>2$?

This is true. It is basically the fact that $x\in \Bbb Z[\alpha]$ is a unit iff $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(x)=\pm 1$ where $K=\operatorname{Frac}(\Bbb Z[\alpha])$.
Consider $m_f:\Bbb Z[x]/(p)\to\Bbb Z[x]/(p), g\mapsto gf$. Now $\Bbb Z[x]/(p)$ is a free $\Bbb Z$-module of rank $\deg p$ and it turns out that $\det m_f=N(f)$, so $|N(f)|=1$ iff $m_f$ is invertible iff $f$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z[x]/(p)$.
That $\det m_f=N(f)$ follows from basic field theory. For example, let $R=\Bbb Z[x]/(p)$ and $K=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ ($R$ is an integral domain). Then by field theory $\det m_f=N_{K/\Bbb Q}(\overline f)$ and $N_{K/\Bbb Q}(\overline f)=\prod_{\sigma:K\to\Bbb C}\sigma(\overline f)=\prod_{i=1}^nf(a_i)$. Or we can think of it as follows: Tensor by $\Bbb C$ to get $m_f\otimes 1_{\Bbb C}:\Bbb C[x]/(p)\to \Bbb C[x]/(p)$. Now $\Bbb C[x]/(p)=\prod_{i=1}^n \Bbb C[x]/(x-a_i)$. On every factor $m_f$ acts as multiplication by $f(a_i)$, so the determinant (which is unchanged after passing to $\Bbb C$) is the product $\prod_{i=1}^nf(a_i)$.

Thank you for your answer, it's really helpful. Could you please give some reference the determinant and field theory part?

See for example Lang's Algebra VI §5. Basically here the idea is that the characteristic polynomial of $m_f$ is a power of the minimal polynomial, and the constant coefficient of the latter is the product of the conjugates (basically $\prod_{i=1}^nf(a_i)$ after throwing away repetitions), and the multiplicities then work out that the determinant of $m_f$, i.e. the constant coefficient of the characteristic polynomial of $m_f$ up to sign, is this product
